# For each to XSL - variables? recursions?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, recursion

I am not used to functional programming and having hard times figuring out a simple for each loops.

I have this in hand and i need to right the same algorithm in xsl.

```
let the input be a string S consisting of n characters: a1 ... an.
let the grammar contain r nonterminal symbols R1 ... Rr.
This grammar contains the subset Rs which is the set of start symbols.
let P[n,n,r] be an array of booleans. Initialize all elements of P to false.
for each i = 1 to n
  for each unit production Rj -> ai
    set P[i,1,j] = true
for each i = 2 to n -- Length of span
  for each j = 1 to n-i+1 -- Start of span
    for each k = 1 to i-1 -- Partition of span
      for each production RA -> RB RC
        if P[j,k,B] and P[j+k,i-k,C] then set P[j,i,A] = true
if any of P[1,n,x] is true (x is iterated over the set s, where s are all the indices for Rs) then
  S is member of language
else
  S is not member of language
```

I am able to do some but i feel stuck and going into the wrong way.

I learned that I cannot have something like arrays. Even i create a variable which acts like an array i cannot update it.

So i started doing some recursions (by calling templates) but i am still thinking if it is the right way. And if there is another why to implement those nested for eachs without recursion..

Comment: You're right: reverse engineering a functional program from a description of a procedural algorithm is difficult. It's often much better to throw away the algorithm, and start with a description of what the algorithm is intended to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT you are much better off if you avoid using `xsl:for-each`.

**You may want to see the general LR(1) parser written completely in XSLT 2.0 which I implemented in 2007**. It is part of **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** and can be viewed here: http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-lrParse.xsl?view=markup

I have written two quite complicated parser one is for JSON (see http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?revision=1.11&view=markup )

and another, much more complicated, is for XPath 2.0 (the grammar has 209 rules).

A basic tool is a modified YACC that produces the parsing tables for a particular LR(1) grammar as XML documents. These are then fed, together with the input string, to the XSLT implementation of the general LR(1) parser.